# Is it possible to use CKRecord.encodeSystemFields with JSONEncoder

Tags: ios, json, swift, cloudkit, foundation

I see in "[How (and when) do I use iCloud's encodeSystemFields method on CKRecord?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39737190/how-and-when-do-i-use-iclouds-encodesystemfields-method-on-ckrecord#39738006)" how to use NSKeyedArchiver to cache the salient fields of CKRecord. Is there a way to use JSONEncoder with `encodeSystemFields`? My other cache data is saved as JSON so I'd like `encodeSystemFields` to fit with that.

Unfortunately `Data` is not allowed in valid JSON despite being Codable, and fails the test `JSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject`, so I can't just jam the output of `NSKeyedArchiver` into my JSON serialization.

```
let d = Data()
d is Codable // true
// ...encodeSystemFields...
JSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject([d]) // false
let listofd = [d]
JSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject(listofd) // false
let dictofd = ["test":d]
JSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject(dictofd) // false
```

It doesn't matter if `d` is `Data` or `NSMutableData`. I get the same results.

Answer (score 3):

The solution I found was to first serialize using NSKeyedArchiver to NSMutableData, cast it to Data, and use JSONEncoder to encode it again to JSON. It creates less than 2000 bytes of JSON. which overwhelmed my tiny record but that's life.

Here is a working playground for that:

```
import Foundation
import CloudKit

let zoneID1 = CKRecordZoneID(zoneName: "Test.1",
                             ownerName: CKCurrentUserDefaultName)
let recID1 = CKRecordID(recordName: "Test1",
                        zoneID: zoneID1)
let rec1 = CKRecord(recordType: "Test",
                    recordID: recID1)

let cacheNSData = NSMutableData()
let kArchiver = NSKeyedArchiver(forWritingWith: cacheNSData)
rec1.encodeSystemFields(with: kArchiver)
kArchiver.finishEncoding()

cacheNSData.length
let cacheData = cacheNSData as Data

let jEncoder = JSONEncoder()

struct Cache: Codable {
    var title: String
    var blob: Data
}
let cacheItem = Cache(title: "abc", blob: cacheData)

let jData = try jEncoder.encode(cacheItem)
jData.count

String(data: jData, encoding: .utf8)
```